# python dictionary update is not working as expected?

Tags: python

I have my dictionary is like this;

```
dbDict={
  'FuelGrade': '4', 
  'Date': '2019-06-26 00:00:00',
  'UpdateFlag': 0,
  'SiteCode': '4198',
  'FileName': 'Invoices_201906251400.csv'
}
```

and I want to add another value to the same tuple.

```
d = {'Delivery': new_delivery}
dbDict.update(d)
```

I expect the result to be;

```
[
  {
    'FuelGrade': '4', 
    'Date': '2019-06-26 00:00:00',
    'UpdateFlag': 0,
    'SiteCode': '4198',
    'FileName': 'Invoices_201906251400.csv',
    'Delivery': '7285.000'
  }
]
```

But I get;

```
[
  '7285.000',
  {
    'FuelGrade': '4',
    'Date': '2019-06-26 00:00:00',
    'UpdateFlag': 0,
    'SiteCode': '4198',
    'FileName': 'Invoices_201906251400.csv'
  }
]
```

What Im doing wrong here?

Comment: It works for me

Comment: try it in a fresh kernel/session

Comment: you need to add the full code, expected result got extra data which you haven't mentioned

Comment: This `dbDict['Delivery'] = '7285.000'`?

Comment: Why would your expected result be a ``dict`` wrapped in a ``list``? The code you provided will not create a ``list``. Please provide a [mcve], so we're all looking at the same code, otherwise it's hard to help.

Comment: @U10-Forward No it is not working to me. I use python 2.7

Comment: @Ratha It works with 2.7 as well

Comment: @MikeScotty yes, my dictionary value is a subset of another dictionary.(i store multiple values for a single key)

Comment: wait, where did the list come from? I think there's an issue with the mcve here. why are you expecting a list of dict in output if you state your dbDict is just a dict?

Comment: @U10-Forward Thanks I figured out my issue. It has to be  dbDict[key].update(d)

Comment: @Ratha That won't work for me just telling you, i guess the code you posted isn't the question you're asking

Answer (score 1):

If you want the dictionary to be wrapped inside a list then you might try this

```py
#new_delivery = '7285.000' 
dbDict={
  'FuelGrade': '4',
  'Date': '2019-06-26 00:00:00',
  'UpdateFlag': 0,
  'SiteCode': '4198',
  'FileName': 'Invoices_201906251400.csv'
}

dbDict = [dbDict]
d = {'Delivery': new_delivery}
dbDict[0].update(d)
print (dbDict)
```